# Read Comments in Tasks via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, 2016, jsom, tasks, comments

I am trying to read the comments of a task list in SharePoint 2016 by using JavaScript.

Right now I get the latest comment using:

```
var comment = oListItem.get_item('Comments');
```

But how can I read all comments and how I can get more information like the person who wrote this comment?

Comment: Is "Append Changes to Existing Text" is set to "Yes" for your Comments column?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the below code to get the version history of Comments field,

```
function getFieldHistory (itemId, fieldName) { //Get each item version history with comment using SPServices

var HTML='';
var ItemID ="", AdditionalComments= "";
var i = 1;
$().SPServices({
           operation: "GetVersionCollection",
           strlistID: "{A4538568-2FC1-44E2-BAFC-D5DB2C64FF0D}",
           strlistItemID: itemId,
           strFieldName: fieldName,
           completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xData.responseText);
                        $xml = $(xmlDoc);                            
                        var values = $xml.find("Versions > Version").each(function () {

                          AdditionalComments = $(this).attr(fieldName);
                          var Editor= $(this).attr("Editor");
                          Editor=Editor.substring(0,Editor.indexOf(','));
                          Editor=Editor.split('#')[1];
                          var temp= $(this).attr("Modified");
                          tempModified=temp.split('T')[0];
              tempModified= new Date(temp);
              Modified=(tempModified.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + tempModified.getDate() + '/' +  tempModified.getFullYear();                                        

            HTML +='<div>'+Editor+' ('+Modified+'): '+AdditionalComments+' | </div><br/>';

        i++;        
             });      
     }

  });
```

}

for more information, refer the below link,

1. http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-read-the-version-history-of-multiline-column-from-list-in-office-365-sharepoint-2013-page/
2. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29559.sharepoint-hosted-apps-working-with-version-history-of-multiple-lines-of-text-column.aspx
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24423657/sharepoint-2013-get-splistitem-versions-via-rest

Comment: What is the different between fieldName and feld?

Comment: You need not pass anything for Field, it's just an array to get all the history values

Comment: I have updated the code, and removed field.

Comment: yes, thank you. But do you have an idea why i get an "undefined" back?

Comment: Where do you get "undefined" ? you need to set your list id here in this line, strlistID: "{A4538568-2FC1-44E2-BAFC-D5DB2C64FF0D}",

Comment: Kindly share your complete code, so  that we will look into it and tell you the right solution

Comment: I sent the code as answer below.

Comment: I found the problem. If I add the line: console.log(Editor+","+Modified+","+AdditionalComments);   
I get all relevant information. It seems so that there is an error in the HTML variable

Comment: Great. If yo find my answer useful kindly upvote and accept it as answer so that it will be helpful for others too in future